# android how to send multi label data on return

Tags: android, android-activity

sorry my english is no good

i want when user click button, a new activity will starts and return data , i make this

#### first activity

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(EditCustomerProfile.this, Address.class), 1);
            }
        });
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String s = data.getData().toString();
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_edit_customer_profile_address);
        et.setText(s);
    }
```

#### second activity

```
Intent resultsIntent = new Intent();
        String data = "adsfasd";
        resultsIntent.setData(Uri.parse(data));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultsIntent);
        finish();
```

it work good, i want not just send one string, i want to send 3 strings like "city", "street", "home" , are there a way to return labeled data like

```
intent.setdata("city", "roma");
intent.setdata("street", "colicano");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can do it. Just place the key/value in intent by using `putExtra()`

Example:

```
Intent resultsIntent = new Intent();
resultsIntent .putExtra("city", "Ahmedabad");
resultsIntent .putExtra("street", "Ahmedabad");
resultsIntent .putExtra("home", "India");
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultsIntent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this instead

```
intent.putExtra("city", "roma");
intent.putExtra("street", "colicano");
```